# graph database for social network

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, social-networking

I am doing a system similar to a social network. The number max of users must be eventually  50.000 or 70.000 at best.

At the moment i am using mysqli+prepared statments. The ERD have now 30 tables, eventually may reach to 40 tables.

So, my question is: i never used a graph database...i have the ERD done by mysql workbench and some code already developed. For the number expected of the users in this project,  is recommended change from MySQL to a graph database? my sql code and database model can be availed? there is any advantage with this change?

what do you think ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Graphs are nice and fast when stored in SQL, if you've access to recursive queries (which is not the case in MySQL, but which are available in [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/plpgsql-statements.html)) and your queries involve a max-depth criteria (which is probably your case on a social network), or if they're indexed properly.

There are multiple methods to index graphs. In your case your graph probably isn't dense, as in you're dealing with multiple forests which are nearly independent (you'll usually be dealing with tightly clustered groups of users), so you've plenty options.

The easiest to implement is a transitive closure (which is, basically, pre-calculating all of the potential paths is called). In your case it may very well be partial (say, depth-2 or depth-3). This allows to fully index related nodes in a separate table, for very fast graph queries. Use triggers or stored procedures to keep it in sync.

If your graph is denser than that, you may want to look into using a [GRIPP index](http://edoc.hu-berlin.de/series/informatik-berichte/207/PDF/207.pdf). Much like with nested sets, the latter works best (as in updated fastest) if you drop the `(rgt - lft - 1) / 2` = number of children property, and use float values for lft/rgt instead of integers. (Doing so avoids to reindex entire chunks of the graph when you insert/move nodes.)

Comment: thanks for your answer. i have to admit, your answer is too much technical to me. at the end i have the same question. In my case, i must change or not to a graph database?

Comment: Short answer is: no, if you can deal with a couple of triggers; if you cannot or don't want to, you'll want to look into learning a new tech (e.g. Allegrograph)... Graph indexing is *hard* whichever way you deal with it...

Comment: That said, seriously... Look into recursive queries in Postgres. It's the simplest solution available if you're restricting your queries with a max-depth constraint.

Comment: the sgbd that i am using for now is mysql. What do you mean with max-depth constraint? sorry again. if you know any good article about this subject i will be grateful :)

Comment: No no. What I'm meaning is (in Postgres) something like: with recursive nodes as (select id, null as parent_id, 1 as depth from node union all select node.id, node.parent_id, depth + 1 as depth from node join nodes as parent on parent.id = node.parent_id where node.depth < 2) select * from nodes; That one is potentially plenty fast if you inject an id criteria in the with statement.

Comment: the main problem is that i never used other than MySQL DBMS. all sql code that i have is for mysql. God, this is a big problem.

Comment: You mean not wanting/having time to to learn new stuff is the problem? :-) Seriously, look into Postgres. It's less permissive with fantasy (which is actually good in the long run), it has a much better optimizer, and many more features than MySQL.